# UPnP portforwarding persist

Tags: linux, router, portforwarding, gateway, upnp

I'm trying to make a portforwarding for different ports for communications, but it seems they are lost on reboot.

I'm using a script to make them, and it uses the following syntax:

```
upnpc -a 192.168.1.95 22 22 TCP
...
```

Since my system is made to actually stress the gateway to reboot, I need to have these ports open after a reboot. I could do it in the software (running the script if connection lost), but I don't want to do that unless it is absolutely necessary.

Do you have some idea of how to make a portforwarding with UPnP such that the forwarding is persisted after a reboot?

Comment: It may depend on the router, but I suspect it's not possible. UPnP is dynamic and temporary, it wouldn't be saved in any permanent configuration of the router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port mappings are specifically *not* required to be persistent between gateway reboots, clients are supposed to keep an eye on the mappings and re-map when needed. WANIPConnection spec v2 also does not even allow indefinite mappings: another reason to keep the client running as long as you need the mapping to exist.